# call javascript in html block after load by Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I have a PHP page that can be loaded two way. it can be directly embedded on a page using includes(), or another page that is made to load the first page on user demand using AJAX. My problem comes with these lines of code:

```
echo "<script>";
    echo "we_start_slide('" . $we_gallery['gallery_name'] . "', " . $we_gallery['display']->output() . ", " . $we_gallery['settings']['slide_time'] . ");";
    echo "we_slide_show_btns('" . $we_gallery['gallery_name'] . "');";
echo "</script>";
```

This works great on direct loads. However AJAX, as you know, doesn't run javascripts when it's loaded. Because the code requires dynamic variables only known to the PHP script I can't just call the functions in the AJAX function. I was wondering if there is anyway to tell JavaScript to run the contents of that script tag after it loads?

Comment: you should probably do something in the `success` part of the ajax. If you're just echoing, you'll get the commands back as a string which you can eval if necessary, otherwise, retrieving the data back as a json would be smarter.

Answer (score 0):

Put the js script inside the ajax done function

```
$.ajax({

}).done(function() {
  <?php
     echo "<script>";
     echo "we_start_slide('" . $we_gallery['gallery_name'] . "', " . $we_gallery['display']->output() . ", " . $we_gallery['settings']['slide_time'] . ");";
     echo "we_slide_show_btns('" . $we_gallery['gallery_name'] . "');";
     echo "</script>";
  ?>
});
```

For reference here is jquery ajax api http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

There is a few options. Note counselledCount: txt is a post variable, so on the page which processes your ajax request access it with `$_POST["counselledCount"]`
Here is another example:

```
$.post("../includes/process-results.php", {counselledCount: txt, currentPageReset: "yes"}, function(result){
        showAjaxResult(result);
});
```

now instead of using ajax done, on the page which processes the ajax request and sends that request back send your script back with the request.

```
$request = "<script>";
$request .= "we_start_slide('" . $we_gallery['gallery_name'] . "', " . $we_gallery['display']->output() . ", " . $we_gallery['settings']['slide_time'] . ");";
$request .= "we_slide_show_btns('" . $we_gallery['gallery_name'] . "');";
$request .= "</script>";
```

Comment: ajax does not have access to the PHP variables.

Comment: Ajax loads the code. the variables do not exist when the original AJAX is loaded. I need to get it after the Ajax runs.

Comment: Are you sending the ajax request to a php file. if so just put them in a session and grab theb in the code your using to process the ajax request

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Check the php manual, http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Basically start the session and save variables to session values. Then start session in file which processes ajax request and set variables from session values.
Ajax can make things complecated. This should help you though :)

Comment: You have it back wards. Ajax is created befor the php. so there is no way to use any php script in the ajax function.

Comment: I have provided another solution for you :)
You can have done it before

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was eval()

```
eval(document.getElementById('slide_start').innerHTML);
```

by adding a id to the script tag I could pull the script into the the call back function then use eval() to execute it Thank you A. lau for pointing me the right way.